# WPML Translated Term

Tags: translation, plugin-wpml

Since I posted on their forum and I didn't got any answer, here I am, asking the same question again. So:

I made a script that add the posibility to add an image and change the order for the terms of a custom taxonomy (called itinerary).

So i use this way of getting each term, one by one (there are only up to 10 terms, so i don't think will be any performance penalties):

```
$term = get_term_by('id', $itinerary_id, 'itinerary' );
```

then get the image, description, url and so on.

The problem i have, however, is that i must have multilanguage content in a way that keeps the custom order AND custom image, so the site admin doesn't have to add images for each language (10terms * 6 languages * other images every week doesn't sound like fun!)

I tried to dig a little into WPML sql tables but I didn't found anything that relates to both (i'm playing now only with 2 languages, english and italian) languages

So i was wondering if there is something like `get_translated_term()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually there is already in their API something for this:

```
icl_object_id(ID, custom_taxonomy_name, return_original_if_missing,language_code)
```

Works like a charm.

More read on this : [Language Dependent IDs](http://wpml.org/documentation/support/creating-multilingual-wordpress-themes/language-dependent-ids/)

Comment: This answer should be selected as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post and my answer will thus primarily be for the googlers out there (how I got here).

I liked the idea of being able to just using a function like get_translated_term() as proposed above. So I wrote it (put in your functions.php):

```
function get_translated_term($term_id, $taxonomy, $language) {

    $translated_term_id = icl_object_id($term_id, $taxonomy, true, $language);

    $translated_term_object = get_term_by('id', $translated_term_id, $taxonomy);

    return $translated_term_object->name;
}
```

Then on any given place in your theme you can call the function as follows:

```
echo get_translated_term($term_id, 'taxonomy name', ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE);
```

Answer (score 1):

WPML API has been updated, you should use [this filter](https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_object_id/) instead. You will save yourself of `function_exists()` too.